# Installing a couple of bundles automatically with OSGi

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, p2

I'm looking for a way to automatically install a couple of bundles into an OSGi application, ideally by some kind of batch file / console script so as to allow us to embed it into our build process.

The ideal situation would allow me to just pass the update site URLs to the console and have it download and install them as that would spare from having to install the jars one by one.

Is this possible? Beware that the application I'm talking about is *not* Eclipse although it contains a couple of Eclipse plugin jars in its bundles directory. I reckon this fact may well imply a slightly different approach to the situation, although I'm not totally sure.

At the moment I'm in control of the application's OSGi console (p2), so I guess that would be the right tool to use, from what I've read.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to go about this (apart from using p2 which you already mention):

1. Use the Apache Felix Gogo shell, which has commands to install bundles from a URL, and create a script for that that is executed at startup.
2. Use the Apache Felix File Install bundle, which allows you to put all bundles in a "hot deploy" folder and automatically installs them.
3. Use Apache ACE, which is a full blown provisioning solution that allows you to map artifacts to target systems.
4. Use a Bnd feature to create an executable jar that embeds both the OSGi framework and all bundles and launches them when you start the jar.
5. Use Apache Karaf features, which allow you to define a list of URLs as a feature and install that feature (using a shell similarly to #1).

There's a lot more to say about each of them, but these are the most-used options I'm aware of.

Comment: Hey. I'm trying to understand if there is a conceptual difference between "installing a bundle" and "installing from an update site". Is there? I had the vague impression that that is, indeed, the case. If there is a positive answer to the question, what I am looking for is to install from the update site, and not install individual bundles. Each one of the update sites contains lots of bundles, and I'd really like to avoid having to install them all individually if possible.

Comment: In OSGi, there is only the concept of "installing a bundle". No matter what code you use on top of that, in the end, it's a call to BundleContext's installBundle(..) method.

Comment: That's what I thought. So I guess what I am looking after is not an OSGi solution, but an Eclipse solution, as to avoid the pain of having to manually install a whole lot of bundles.

Comment: All of the above essentially do that (after you have defined once what the set of bundles is that make up your application). Which one you prefer depends on preference and use cases.